# Catalogsearch encodes query string for sort/limit in toolbar

Tags: magento-1.9, template, catalogsearch, bug, character-encoding

If my search contains special chars like `ü`, `ä` they are encoded to `%C3%BC` for example.

The strange thing is, it does work correctly in one template, but not in another one.

**Template 1:** simple links ... works without encoding

```
<?php foreach ($this->getAvailableLimit() as  $_key=>$_limit): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getLimitUrl($_key) ?>"<?php if($this->isLimitCurrent($_key)): ?> class="active"<?php endif; ?>><span><span><?php echo $_limit ?></span></span></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Template 2:** dropdown ... values are encoded

```
<select class="select--wd select--wd--sm"  onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
    <?php foreach ($this->getAvailableLimit() as  $_key=>$_limit): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $this->getLimitUrl($_key) ?>"<?php if($this->isLimitCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
            <?php echo $_limit ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

- toolbar block is **not** rewritten, it's still `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar`.
- it's the same server, just another website with another template

I've solved this with using `urldecode()`, **but** i still want to know where the different behavoir comes from.

Comment: db charsets  perhaps?

Comment: No, it's the same DB for all shops (normal multistore setup with 3 websites)

Comment: what happens if you htmlencode / decode the <option> value?

Comment: What do you mean? Using `urldecode` works ... ?!?

Comment: excuse me sv3n - I'm not reading clearly this morning :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In template 2, when using a select element, the link is called with:

```
setLocation(this.value)
```

Since Magento 1.9.3.0, the implementation for this method in `js/varien/js.js` looks like that:

```
`window.location.href = encodeURI(url);`
```

The link is already encoded when it is inserted into the page, but `encodeURI` encodes it another time and therefore breaks the page.

See also [Catalog Search Sorting Broken With Umlauts / Special Characters](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/186820/142.)